# jQuery Click function doesn't work on first child

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

jQuery Click function isn't working on first child of li becomes '.contracted' as on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SheikhNaveed/8hT64/3/)

```
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li class="contracted">
    <a href="#">
      <span>L1<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#">
      <span>L2<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to move click function at bottom as well. But it isn't working. Full working example is given in jsFiddle.

```
$('.contracted').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().attr('class', 'expanded');
  $('ul.expanded li.activeLesson').attr('class', 'selected');
  $('ul.expanded li:not(.selected)').attr('class', '');
});
```

Comment: Where do you set the class from "expanded" back to "contracted"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$('.contracted').click(...)` code will bind a click handler to any elements with that class *at the moment that code runs* - this will not automatically work on other elements that have the class added later. If you want it to work on any li element that has the `contracted` class at the time of the click use a delegated event handler set up via `.on()`:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li.contracted', function() {
   ...
});
```

This binds the click handler to all `ul` elements, but then when a click occurs jQuery checks if the clicked item is a descendant of the `ul` which matches the selector in the second argument and only calls your function if it does.